# Can SP2013 REST End Points used to work with SP2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, rest

Initially I was working in SharePoint 2013 site with REST API from [Get to know the SharePoint 2013 REST service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380.aspx) here, Now suddenly the requirement changed, Now I have to work with same requirement but with SharePoint 2010 Site collection.

Can I still use the same REST End Points to work with SharePoint 2010? I tried but not able to use the same REST Calls with SharePoint 2010.

Please provide some reference link if its possible/impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use the same end points as like 2013. REST API in 2010 is very limited. There is option for Lists only as far as I know.

```
_vti_bin/listdata.svc/<list name>
```

You can perform GET, POST, UPDATE and DELETE request through above end point in a particular list.

[Using the REST Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx)

Some query operator like `$select`, `$filter`, `$expand` and `$orderby` works in GET request.

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/InventoryLocations()?$filter=startswith(Part/SKU,'sku')&$orderby=Part/SKU&$expand=Part
```

[List Items manipulation via REST API in SharePoint 2010](https://blog.vgrem.com/2014/03/22/list-items-manipulation-via-rest-api-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: Ok Thanks. Just for now if you know then can you tell me can I Create Library, update Library Items , Create folder, Assign content types, and assign permission with REST API 2010?

Comment: I did not try to  Create Library, update Library Items , Create folder, Assign content types, and assign permission with REST API 2010 yet. I also don't know it is possible or not. You can perform CRUD on a list that's all I know. For your requirement, you have to go for JSOM, I gauge

Comment: Not REST but SOAP interfaces, check out SPServices

Answer (score 2):

Nope, SP2010 has only ODATA v2.0 endopoint.
[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx)
It is very similar to v3.0 api, but less powerful.